# Easier Way to find Files in eclipse Path

Tags: java, eclipse, filenotfoundexception

I am executing a simple program in java spring which uses "spring.xml" but eclipse is not able to determine location of this file. As I am sure that I am creating this file in root directory ie, SpringDemo simply providing spring.xml should work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I tried giving both path real and absolute but it did not work, ie ,the path information by right click->properties under resource

Structure of project:

[image: Structure of project]

Comment: You should read up on what the classpath is.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am missing something? I did'nt understood you are asking or suggesting?

Comment: I suggest you read up on classpaths.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis   I tried some thing similar to this but it didn't worked InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                                .getResourceAsStream("spring.xml");
will try it once again! or can you tell me how exactly it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access `spring.xml` as a class path resource at the root of the classpath, but it is not on the classpath. Either add it to the classpath or use a `FileSystemResource`.